# logo to stay centered

Tags: html, css

I am viewing [p-ng.com](http://p-ng.com) in firefox, when it is viewed with the bookmark sidebar, the logo is not centred.

**Example with sidebar:**

[image]

When I view the page without the bookmark sidebar, it looks like this.

**Example without sidebar:**

[image]

Even so, the logo doesn't  seem to stay centered.
Thanks for any suggestions.

**CSS**

```
.site-title {
font-size: 32px;
font-weight: 400;
line-height: 1.2;
}

.site-title a,
.site-title a:hover {
margin:0;
}

.header-image .site-title > a {
background: url(images/logo.png) no-repeat top center;
margin-left: 625px;  
margin-top: -95px;   
width: 87px;
height: 87px;
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
background:#E5E5E5;
overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/css-center-position-absolute-div/

Comment: could you provide the html as well.

Answer (score 2):

You have so many unnecessary declarations, the reason it's not centering to the viewport is because you have `position: absolute` and a bunch of unneeded margins.

Change your css to this.

**CSS**

```
.header-image .site-title > a {
    background-position: url(images/logo.png) no-repeat top center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 87px;
    height: 87px;
    background: #E5E5E5;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you have all the different margins, widths and then finally a `position: absolute` on top of that, but here's an easy way to center your logo :

```
.header-image .site-title > a {
    position: absolute;
    width: 87px;
    height: 87px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);    
    background:#E5E5E5;    
}
```

If it needs to be vertically centered within its container as well, you can add this :

```
.header-image .site-title > a{
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

For the browser support of the `transform`property (and to see which vendor prefixes you need), refer to this : http://caniuse.com/#search=transform

Comment: thank you, this worked but had to change top:50% as it disappeared off the page

Answer (score 0):

`Position` your logo `relative` to a container of `width: 100%`, then you can set `margin: 0 auto` - this way you can also lose the `margin-left` property.

Example:

```
.parentContainer {
width: 100%;
}

.logo {
margin:0 auto;
position: relative
}
```